# Preg_match PHP Folders

Tags: php, preg-match

Can someone please show me how i can preg_match this so that it just shows the file name??

Music/dnb/Crazy Talk_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3

show it will just show.

Crazy Talk_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3

Having a right pain trying to get this to work, wasting far too much time on it any help please???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = basename('Music/dnb/Crazy Talk_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3');
```

if you're insisting on using regexps it could be:

```
preg_match('~/([^/]+)$~', 'Music/dnb/Crazy Talk_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3', $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Just thought i would pick your brain about another issue see if you can help.

Comment: Music/dnb/Crazy Talk_Tantrum Desire_192.mp3 if i am using a foreach loop to scan through loads of files how can i just grab the folders so for above just show Music/dnb/ ???

Comment: Actually no worries just found pathinfo();